# Tool for Job scheduling with logs instead of Jenkins (Rails project)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jenkins

I have more than 30 rake tasks added to Jenkins for scheduling jobs. (Rails project)

But the jenkins server goes down frequently and uses 100% of CPU at most of the time.

Please suggest me a better job scheduler instead of Jenkins, which is also capable of 
doing steps like

- Notify an email when jobs fail
- Log the jobs terminal output
- Add dependency to jobs

Comment: Do the rake jobs load the whole Rails environment and is called frequently?

Comment: Yes, it seems to always load the Rails environment as like we do it in the terminal.

Comment: If jobs are frequent, Rails env loading may take most of the time. Sidekiq + sidetiq avoids this (Long living single process doing scheduled work). It is more related to Rails though, not sure if those fits your Jenkins requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to come out as "recommend me a CI server".

But - why does Jenkins fall over and/or use 100% CPU most of the time? I'd be looking at why this is. My experience of Jenkins is that it is pretty stable and low overhead. If your hardware / OS / something else is flaky or just under provisioned for the task then swapping Jenkins out isn't going to fix that.

Comment: so should i increase my server performance? to accommodate all the rake tasks?

Comment: Maybe. Or maybe add another server. But first I'd look at which resources are being consumed by what.

Comment: I saw only one set of tasks are utilizing much resource..
is it possible in jenkins to operate with clusters? so that one jenkins master runs all these jobs in a cluster which shares load?

Comment: Yes, Jenkins can handle bigger nodes and multiple nodes to perform jobs. I've got a blog post describing a simple setup of a higher-powered slave on EC2 here: http://splashinapond.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/jenkins-slave-on-ec2.html  See also the comment from lulalala on splitting environment setup from task if the jobs are frequent and the environment slow to start.